Tracking a real-world object using Object Detection in visionOS
There is no error shown, I am trying to detect an object using ImageTrackingProvider, I already added the specific image in AR ressource called "ref" and also the authorization like 'NSWorldSensingUsageDescription', 'Privacy - Tracking Usage Description' ...
When I run the code everything seems fine, it loads the image.
Here is my console::

Reference images loaded: [ReferenceImage(name: "Imagee", physicalSize: (0.140 m, 0.140 m)] Loaded image: Imagee, Physical size: 0.14000000059604645 x 0.14000000059604645 meters
Starting ARKit session...
ARKit session started. Waiting for image detection...

Here is my code:
import SwiftUI
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent
import CoreGraphics


@MainActor
struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @State private var arkitSession = ARKitSession()
    @State private var entityMap: [UUID: ModelEntity] = [:]
    @State private var rootEntity = Entity()
    
    private let imageTracking: ImageTrackingProvider
    
    init() {
        let loadedImages = ReferenceImage.loadReferenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ref")
        imageTracking = ImageTrackingProvider(referenceImages: loadedImages)
        
        print("Reference images loaded: \(loadedImages)")
        for image in loadedImages {
            print("Loaded image: \(image.name ?? "Unnamed"), Physical size: \(image.physicalSize.width) x \(image.physicalSize.height) meters")
        }
    }
    
    private func updateImage(_ anchor: ImageAnchor) {
        let circle = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.05)
        if entityMap[anchor.id] == nil {
            let circleEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: circle)
            circleEntity.model?.materials = [SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: false)]
            entityMap[anchor.id] = circleEntity
            rootEntity.addChild(circleEntity)
            print("Object detected")
        } else if let entity = entityMap[anchor.id] {
            entity.transform = Transform(matrix: anchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
            print("Updated position for anchor ID: \(anchor.id)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            content.add(rootEntity)
        }
        .task {
            do {
                print("Starting ARKit session...")
                try await arkitSession.run([imageTracking])
                print("ARKit session started. Waiting for image detection...")
                for await update in imageTracking.anchorUpdates {
                    print("Anchor update received.")
                    updateImage(update.anchor)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
}
//ContentView
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ImmersiveView()
    }
}

#Preview(windowStyle: .automatic) {
    ContentView()
}
//Main
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestVisionTrackerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

Edit
I have added 6 images with a resolution of 480x480 pixels, without a background, and with a real size of 20x20 cm, but nothing is getting detected. I don't know why.
Is there anything I missed in the code section?

There is a new ARKit's anchor type called ObjectAnchor in visionOS 2.0.
@available(visionOS 2.0, *)
public struct ObjectAnchor : TrackableAnchor, @unchecked Sendable, Equatable

Also, you can find its equivalent in RealityKit 2024 and Reality Composer Pro 2.0.
@available(macOS 15.0, iOS 18.0, visionOS 2.0, *)
case referenceObject(from: AnchoringComponent.ObjectAnchoringSource)

Read this post for details.
